# Laravel nested eager loading can't work as expected

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

This problem has troubled me for days, I cannot solve this problem until now, so I have to ask for help.

Below is the relevant code snippet:

**Model** Category.php

```
public function child()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Category', 'pid', 'id');
}

public function logs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Log', 'cate_id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Product', 'cate_id');
}

public function newProduct()
{
    return $this->products()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}

public function latestLog()
{
    return $this->logs()->where([
               'product_id' => $this->newProduct()->first()->id,
               'status'     => 1,
           ])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

**Controller** CategoryController.php

```
public function getLatestLog()
{
    // Category with id 1 with nested eager loading
    $subCategory = Category::find(1)
                   ->with(['child.newProduct', 'child.latestLog'])
                   ->first()->child;

    // Get latest log for subCategory with id 3
    dd($subCategory->find(3)->latestLog);
}
```

In this case, I want to use nested eager loading to get latest log. But what bothers me is when I add `child.checkLatestLog` it just outputs empty, but when I delete it, it will output normally.

I think the problem is related to the `$this->newProduct()->first()->id` variable. Because I tried to manually enter a product ID that exists in the log table, it's worked normal.

It may be my fault, but I don't know where it was wrong. I would like to thank you for asking for help.

---

**update**

A solution for this Question:

```
public function latestLog()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Http\Models\Log',
        'App\Http\Models\Product',
        'cate_id',
        'product_id',
        'id',
        'id'
    )->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Comment: `latestLog` has to be a relationship.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thanks for your reply! I changed the function `latestLog()` to a relationship `$this->logs()->where([ ... ])` but still can't get the expected result.

Comment: Can you try `$this->newProduct->first()->id` instead of `$this->newProduct()->first()->id` I mean remove **()** symbols.

Comment: @MakashovNurbol Thanks for your suggestion, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$this->newProduct()->first()->id`: You can't use eager loading with model-dependent attributes like that.

You'll have to use a JOIN solution.